# Pytest throws a DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

Tags: python, flask, session, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm trying to test the deletion of a user, however, although the returned status for the API call is correct after that I'd like to check if the field 'deleted' in the database is actually changed to True.

Here's my pytest:

```
 def test_delete_user_valid(self, user_to_delete, admin_access_token, client):
        db.session.add(user_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        assert user_to_delete.deleted is False
        request, status, headers = client.put(
            f"/user/delete/{user_to_delete.id}", token_auth=admin_access_token
        )
        assert status == 204
        user = User.query.filter(User.id == user_to_delete.id).first()
        assert user is not None
        assert user.deleted is True
```

And here's the error:

```
./tests/test_api/test_user.py::TestUser::test_delete_user_valid Failed: [undefined]sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x7f4b15e17a90> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bhk3)
```

And in case anyone needs to see the API endpoint:

```
@api.put("/user/delete/<user_id>")
@required_role(UserRole.ADMIN)
def delete_user_by_id(user_id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    user.deleted = True
    db.session.commit()
    return "", 204
```

I tried refreshing the session but it didn't help. I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions or workarounds that may still be effective to test the code.